# If all SQL is doing is SELECT, is there an advantage to using a view vs a SPROC

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, view

If all SQL is doing is SELECT, is there an advantage to using a view vs a SPROC.
From my point of view, it's purely organizational, but I am wondering if there is a good reason for using views when all a SPROC is doing is SELECTs and has no writes to the DB.
I'm on Sql Server 2008 but this can probably apply to other SQL server products

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views are meant to abstract out the details of the underlying table and provide a window to the data, the way you want it to appear.

Stored procedures achieve a specific task and optionally take parameters that would be used during the task execution.

If you would like to run a specific task by taking arguments from the users, then you can create a stored procedure.

If you just want to expose data in a given way and leave further filtering, if required, to the users, you can create a view.

Comment: -1: You can pass a where clause to the view: `select * from v_your_view where your_column = 1`

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, That's what I meant by "the user providing the filter", where as in case of a stored proc, you would have already decided what columns to filter on and the user only provides the values for those filters.

Comment: Quite an ambiguous way to say that. Maybe you can edit it? That would allow me to remove the downvote.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, Edited out the ambiguous portion.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the security advantage of encapsulating specific data for specific roles, there's also the advantage of being able to create an [index on the view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Here are some specific performance advantages, from the MSDN link:

> - Aggregations can be precomputed and stored in the index to minimize expensive computations during query execution.
> - Tables can be prejoined and the resulting data set stored.
> - Combinations of joins or aggregations can be stored.